# How to pass parameter to jQuery . animate option object complete property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

Question title is confusing, I know. it also make my search hard to find a solution.

assume I have these codes, how can I pass parameter to `complete` or `step` when .animate() option is an external object?

```
var someObj = {
    onComplete: function(e) {
        console.log(e); // return undefined
    },

    onStep: function(e) {
        console.log(e); // return undefined too
    },
}

var optionObj = {
    duration: 300,
    easing: 'linear',
    complete: someObj.onComplete(e), // this is not working
    step: someObj.onStep(e) // this is not working
}

$('div').animate({width: "500px", height: "500px"}, optionObj);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass your own parameters to those callbacks and to ensure that `this` is correctly set to `someObj` within those callbacks you will probably need additional closures:

```
var optionObj = {
    duration: 300,
    easing: 'linear',
    complete: function() {
        someObj.onComplete(e);  // assumes 'e' is defined somewhere
    },
    step: function(now, fx) {   // jQuery automatically supplies these parameters
        someObj.onStep(e);      // so you need to pass your own instead
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your object like below. Removed the (e) from `complete: someObj.onComplete` as using `(e)` would be calling the function and assigns the return value to the `optionObj.complete` and `optionObj.step` which is `undefined`.

```
var optionObj = {
    duration: 300,
    easing: 'linear',
    complete: someObj.onComplete, 
    step: someObj.onStep 
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mL5Fy/

Comment: NB: this will _not_ result in the correct `this` inside the two callbacks.

Comment: this was the first thing that I do, but still getting undefined